# setting the http referrer using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following C# code that creates a http request for a given url although I need to view the webpage.  Is it possible to create a web request to allow me to control the http referrer value with also being able to see the destination web page?  Right now it looks like this app sets the referrer correctly although I want to see http://localhost:8000 in a browser when the app finishes..

Many thanks,

```
class Program
{
    const string MyUrl = "http://localhost:8000";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(MyUrl);

        myHttpWebRequest.Referer = args[0];

        var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        var streamResponse = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        if (streamResponse != null) streamResponse.Close();

        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Referer to the site is:{0}", myHttpWebRequest.Referer);
        Console.Write(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why would you expect the *request* to change by the time the *response* finishes? The request is just "what you send to the server". When you've sent it, that's what you've sent.

Comment: So, you want to add a GUI to your application that shows the page you just downloaded? Or do you want to show it in the browser?

Comment: What error are you encountering? The Referrer will be set properly in your code above.

Comment: i need to build up a request and then execute it within a browser.

Comment: You want your C# program to construct a request that is then sent through a browser, with the referrer set? I don't know that you can do such a thing with a standalone browser. You might look into using the `WebBrowser` control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: "you want your C# program to construct a request that is then sent through a browser, with the referrer set?" -- YES

Comment: To do that, you'd need some way to tell the browser, "use this referrer." If that's even possible to do, the mechanism would be different for every browser. You'll have to look into browser startup command line options or see if there's an API you can use to set those things before the browser makes the request.